# cocoa how to get the ALREADY mounted unmountable disk

Tags: disk, mount, nsworkspace

**NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification** works well to get the information of just mounted disk.
But how can I get the information of **already** mounted disks before my app start?

command line: "diskutil list" and "diskutil info /" works but there should be a simple programmatically method there.

searched result of "DiskArbitration" or "VolumeToBSDNode example" don't work, IOkit difficult.

BTW, anyone recommend of using this?
[NSWorkspace getFileSystemInfoForPath:isRemovable:isWritable:isUnmountable:description:type:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [`[NSFileManager mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:)?

**Edit:** Here's a snippet of code for how to use this to get removable drives and their volume names.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, nil];
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:0];
for (NSURL *url in urls) {
  NSError *error;
  NSNumber *isRemovable;
  NSString *volumeName;
  [url getResourceValue:&isRemovable forKey:NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey error:&error];
  if ([isRemovable boolValue]) {
    [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", volumeName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Woody, grate!!!! it's almost there with this:NSArray *result = [testM mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:nil options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes]; but can not find out which is the mounted removable, which is the local. And how to convert them into disk name like "HP v125w"? "file://localhost/Volumes/HP%20v125w/"

Comment: tried this with no luck: NSArray *proA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeIdentifierKey,NSURLTypeIdentifierKey,nil];
    NSArray *result = [testM mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:proA options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes];

Comment: Don't have access to xCode at the moment, but could you try [NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey)?

Comment: Yes, the code works! the 150 credit goes to you. One more confirmation: should we use options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes instead of options:0  ?

Comment: @JiulongZhao Thanks for the rep. As far as I can see, hidden volumes tend not to be mounted, and it takes quite a bit of effort to mount them. An example would be the Recovery HD partition. It's should be safe to skip over them unless you have some reason not to.